# Form data loss on Chrome for Android

Tags: php, android, forms, google-chrome

I have a web form with a large number of fields. It's a job application but I run into a very peculiar issue.

The form's action on a separate page is to handle the upload of the data. But when users on Android Chrome fill out the app and submit it, we receive a blank entry on the db. So I know the post data is not null as it is the first check I run it through, but all the field data seems to be blank. The db responds with a true for adding the data so the thank you message still pops up then it redirects to the previous page.

Any ideas why the db is not getting the data correctly? I have no Android device for testing and it's driving me nuts.

[The form page](http://countryinnpetresort.com/careers.php)

Comment: can you show your php script?

Comment: Its huge but i can trim down the redundant part, which one? the one that add the data to the db?

Comment: yes please, the reading from request and adding to db :)